# Display a success custom notice after Placing an Order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, notice

I need to check on the checkout page whether payment has been successful or not and display the message: 'Your payment has been successful', and then redirect to the thank you page (which is customized per product by the plugin Woo Product Tools). I've been trying to find hooks on the Woo documentation, but no luck so far. The latest code I have is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'message_after_payment' );
function message_after_payment(){
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  if ( $order->has_status('processing') ){
    wc_add_notice( __("Your payment has been successful", "test"), "success" );
  }
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't display a "success" notice on checkout page once you submit an order (place an order)… You can do that in Order Received (thankyou) page. Also in your code, `$order_id` is not defined…

So the right hook is `woocommerce_before_thankyou` using `wc_print_notice()` function instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'success_message_after_payment' );
function success_message_after_payment( $order_id ){
    // Get the WC_Order Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->has_status('processing') ){
        wc_print_notice( __("Your payment has been successful", "woocommerce"), "success" );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Addition:** Display a custom html message instead of a Woocommerce notice

Just replace the code line:

```
wc_print_notice( __("Your payment has been successful", "woocommerce"), "success" );
```

with for example this:

```
echo '<p class='cudtom-message"> . __("Your payment has been successful", "woocommerce"), "success" ) . '</p>';
```

You can add your own html as you like around the text message.

Comment: Ok, and isn't there a way to show that message via another method that isn't printing notices??

Comment: I meant if there isn't a way to show that message on the checkout page? Like with a different hook than 'woocommerce_before_thankyou'?? So that the message is displayed after the user clicks 'Place order' and before the redirect happens

Comment: Oh, ok. So my approach of using $order_id was wrong. What about with hooks that don't use $order_id. I've seen other posts here on SO and on Stackexchange that talk about woocommerce_checkout_order_processed and woocommerce_before_checkout_process, but the documentation on them is very vague

Comment: @andressanchez No way… Checkout page doesn't handle this as I said The data is posted and redirected to thankyou page in WooCommerce process after payment is validated (except for COD). End of conversation.

Comment: Ok, will accept your answer. Sorry to be bothering you so much

Comment: @andressanchez You don't bother… What you wanted to do is not possible.